# Regular expression: non greedy search

Tags: regex, notepad++

In this kind of text:

```
['WRK', 'SOCCER', 'CHILD']
['FIN', 'TENNIS', 'CHILD']
['WRK', 'GOLF', 'CHILD']
```

I would like to extract:

```
    'SOCCER', 'CHILD'
    'TENNIS', 'CHILD'
    'GOLF', 'CHILD'
```

I tried:

```
    '.+'{1}?,\s'CHILD'
```

But gives me too much: the first term in single quotes should not be extracted. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```regex
Find:    \['.*?',\s*(.*?)\]
Replace: $1
```

### Demo

This regex pattern matches the first singly quoted term, but does not capture it.  The second term onwards is captured, up to, but not including, the closing square bracket.  We then replace with just the first capture group.

Comment: Thanks. But your solution gives me the entire sentence. I use it in Notepad++ with regular expression search active. But the demo seems to work so I will investigate further.

Comment: I see. Notepad++ highlights the full sentence, but not only the term that is captured. With the replace indeed Notepad++ replaces what needs to be replaced. It works, thanks. I thought I was hoping Notepad++ would only select/highlight the captured part but of course that isn't the case. Thanks !

Comment: I wanted to do that but SO says to wait 5 min :-) Happy to do so then.